# Joining two tables where keys from one table is missing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure what type of join I need to obtain my desired result. As per the below example I am trying to join `table 1` to `table 2` but I am missing Q3 in the first table.

table 1:

| Quarter | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 100 |
| Q2 | 200 |
| Q4 | 300 |

table 2:

| Quarter | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 20 |
| Q2 | 50 |
| Q3 | 70 |
| Q4 | 10 |

I want to join both tables such that I get the following result:

Result:

| Quarter | Sales | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | 100 | 20 |
| Q2 | 200 | 50 |
| Q3 | NULL | 70 |
| Q4 | 300 | 10 |

I have tried to use a FULL OUTER JOIN on `Quarter` from each table. But I think because I'm selecting `table1.Quarter` in the SELECT statement, I am getting NULL where Q3 should be. So essentially, I am getting the following which is incorrect:

| Quarter | Sales | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | 100 | 20 |
| Q2 | 200 | 50 |
| NULL | NULL | 70 |
| Q4 | 300 | 10 |

Do I simply need to use the correct JOIN type, or is the problem a bit more complex than that?

Comment: Your `FULL OUTER JOIN` should work. Maybe do something like `SELECT COALESCE(table1.Quarter, table2.Quarter) quarter, sales, cost...` to make sure you always get the quarter.

Comment: @EdmCoff MySQL doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN`. It only has `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: If you tried to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` you should have gotten a syntax error. Are you sure you're using MySQL as your database?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I was taking the OP's wording at face-value and didn't even look at the DBMS tag. I think my comment still mostly stands if the only outstanding issue is the null in the quarter column. (Probably tag is wrong).

Comment: @EdmCoff Yes, if they're using a DB with outer join, your solution should work. Although if there's a quarter with no sales or costs, it will still be missing. My answer solves that.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I'm actually working in SQL Server, sorry for the confusion. And your solution works well since my dataset can have missing value in the sales and cost columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a synthesized table that has all the quarters.

```
SELECT q.quarter, s.sales, c.cost
FROM (
    SELECT 'Q1' AS quarter
    UNION
    SELECT 'Q2'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Q3'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Q4'
) AS q
LEFT JOIN table1 AS s ON a.quarter = b.quarter
LEFT JOIN table2 AS c ON a.quarter = c.quarter
```

Comment: Why? Table2 already has all quarters. And [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Read the OP's last comment: "since my dataset can have missing value in the sales and cost columns"

Comment: That's example data, real data might not have all quarters.

Comment: When I have real table names I use abbreviations (usually the first letter of the table name) as the aliases. This example doesn't have real table names, so I just used arbitrary aliases.